# Show that $\{w^{1/2}\phi_n\}$ is an orthonormal set in $L^2(D)$ if $\{\phi_n\}$ is an orthonormal set in $L^2_w(D)$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

As mentioned in the title, my problem is:

> Show that $\{w^{1/2}\phi_n\}$ is an orthonormal set in $L^2(D)$ if
>   $\{\phi_n\}$ is an orthonormal set in $L^2_w(D).$

So I know that:

$$\int_D\phi_n(x)\overline{\phi_m(x)}w(x)\;dx = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1, & n=m\\
       0, & n\neq m.
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

For the set $\{w^{1/2}\phi_n\}$ I have:

$$\int_D \sqrt{w(x)}\phi_n(x)\overline{\sqrt{w(x)}\phi_m(x)}\;dx = \int_D \phi_n(x)\overline{\phi_m(x)}\sqrt{w(x)}\overline{\sqrt{w(x)}}\;dx,$$

so I guess my task now is to show that:

$$w(x)=\sqrt{w(x)}\overline{\sqrt{w(x)}}\;\;?$$

This holds for real-valued functions, but what if $w(x)$ is a complex-valued function? Because in my problem it was not stated whether $w(x)$ is complex- or real-valued function. Or do I need to assume that $w(x)$ is a real-valued function? =)

Thnx for any help =)

Comment: In case $w(x)$ is not non-negative the space $L_{w}²(D)$ becomes awkward. Even if $w(x)$ is real but is negative on certain intervals it is no longer a Hilbert space but a Krein space which is much more complicated.